# When performing a select in sqlite with a joined table, an aliased column has a null value

Tags: sqlite, join, alias

I'm trying to join two tables in sqlite with an alias on one of the columns, but when I alias the column, it returns null.

I've got two tables, like this:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM series;
     _id = 1
    name = Castle
    type = show
     who = dan
disabled = 0

sqlite> SELECT * FROM series_meta;
  meta_id = 1
series_id = 1
meta_name = year
meta_type = int
meta_text =
 meta_int = 2009
```

Now, I try the following query: `SELECT _id, name, type, who, disabled, y.meta_int AS year FROM series LEFT JOIN series_meta AS y ON _id=y.series_id AND y.meta_name="year";` I get:

```
     _id = 1
    name = Castle
    type = show
     who = dan
disabled = 0
    year =
```

But if I get rid of the column alias (`SELECT _id, name, type, who, disabled, y.meta_int FROM series LEFT JOIN series_meta AS y ON _id=y.series_id AND y.meta_name="year";`), I get the expected result:

```
     _id = 1
    name = Castle
    type = show
     who = dan
disabled = 0
meta_int = 2009
```

I've tried this with sqlite 3.8.8.2 on Windows 7. I also tried it using python, with the exact same results. Removing the table alias doesn't change anything either.

Is there no way to get this to work with a column alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use as much columns aliases as you want to, you are actually facing a different problem here, this is the usage of `year` as field name.

If y.meta_int is named `year` the result will be `(null)`, while any other name will work:

```
SELECT _id, name, type, who, disabled, y.meta_int tyear
FROM series
LEFT JOIN series_meta AS y ON _id=y.series_id AND y.meta_name="year";
```

Same result without join but here. But what is different is, that here if you use 'year' as field name you will actually get no result at all. Any other name will work:

```
SELECT _id, name, type, who, disabled, y.meta_int AS m_year
FROM series, series_meta AS y
WHERE _id=y.series_id AND y.meta_name="year";
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, single quotes are used for strings, while double quotes are used to quote column names.
So `y.meta_name="year"` compares the contents of the `y.meta_name` column against the contents of the `y.meta_int` column.

For compatibility with buggy databases like MySQL, SQLite also supports single quotes for quoted column names and double quotes for strings, but only when the difference is unambiguous.
You should always use correct SQL syntax:

```
SELECT _id, name, type, who, disabled, y.meta_int AS year
FROM series
LEFT JOIN series_meta AS y ON _id=y.series_id
                          AND y.meta_name = 'year'
```